# Crear columnas de forma dinámica en un tablelayout de android studio

Tags: android

Qué tal, tengo una duda, ¿alguien sabe cómo crear columnas de forma dinámica en una tabla hecha en android, sé cómo agregar las filas, pero necesito que en las columnas me aparezcan ciertos datos que obtengo desde una consulta a un servicio web?

Tengo un Asynctask:

```
private class GetDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IServicioTallasAndroid/ListadoTallasA";
    final String METHOD = "ListadoTallasA";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String ENDPOINTWS = "http://192.1.1.82/SP_Catalogos/ServicioTallasAndroid.svc";



    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        listaTodo.clear();
        SoapObject userRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        userRequest.addProperty("estilo", params[0]);

        xmodelo = params[0].toString();

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(userRequest);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try{
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ENDPOINTWS);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject res= (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject t=(SoapObject)res.getProperty("ListadoTallasAResult");

            for(int i=0; i<t.getPropertyCount(); i++){
                SoapObject bank = (SoapObject)t.getProperty(i);



                String estilo = bank.getProperty("Estilo").toString();
                String tienda = bank.getProperty("Tienda").toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
                String tallas = bank.getProperty("Tallas").toString();
                String cantidad = bank.getProperty("Cantidad").toString();

                p = new Productos(estilo, tienda, tallas, cantidad);



                listaTodo.add(p);

            }
            //respuesta = "Estilo: " + cantidad + "\nTienda: " + costo + "\nTallas: " + descripcion/*envelope.getResponse().toString()*/;

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.miTableLayout);

        for (int z = 0; z < listaTodo.size(); z++) {


            filas = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tvTiendas = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tvCantidad = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tvTallas = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            filas.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            tvTiendas.setText(listaTodo.get(z).getTienda());
            tvCantidad.setText(listaTodo.get(z).getCantidad());
            tvTallas.setText(listaTodo.get(z).getTallas());

            filas.addView(tvTiendas);
            filas.addView(tvCantidad);

            filas.addView(tvTallas);
            //tvItemName1.setText(listaTodo.get(z).getEstilo());
            tl.addView(filas, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        }


    }
}
```

En el método post es donde hago la tabla, pero necesito poner las tallas como columnas y me salen en fila.

Ejemplo:
Introduzco el modelo de un producto y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera columna muestra las tiendas, la segunda la cantidad de producto en existencia y la tercera las tallas.

Comment: como columna? entonces estarían arriba de tienda o de cantidad?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que me quede la cabecera así: Tienda Total XX XL S M....que son las tallas. Y esas tallas dependen del código de producto.

Comment: Aún tienes este problema @Sandra ?

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto un metodo general y ya lo vas modificando a tu gusto:

```
private int NUM_COLS=3
private int NUM_ROWS=2

TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);

for(int i = 0; i<NUM_ROW; i++){
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        table.addView(tableRow);

        for(int j= 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++){
            Button button = new Button(this);
            tableRow.addView(button);

        }
 }
```

Dale lo valores que tu quieras a `NUM_COLS` y `NUM_ROWS` y obviamente en vez de poner un `Button` puedes poner lo que te plazca

Comment: Ok, pero en caso de que mis datos estén guardados en un arraylist, cómo le podría hacer para que me ponga ciertos datos en la fila cabecera?

Comment: Después de tantos intentos pude terminar con esa parte y me sirvió mucho el fragmento de código @Ramosaurio, gracias.