# Rellenar un TableLayout de forma dinámica

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación de Android en la que realizo una carga desde una base de datos. En el siguiente enlace pregunté porqué mi código me daba un fallo, por el cual no me cargaba correctamente la tabla con los datos de la consulta.

[Mal funcionamiento en aplicación de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115341/mal-funcionamiento-en-aplicaci%C3%B3n-de-android/115382?noredirect=1#comment214169_115382)

Después de cambiar mi código según la respuesta de A.Cedano, el programa no responde como debería. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
    int Año = calendario.getYear();
    int Mes = calendario.getMonth()+1;
    int Dia = calendario.getDayOfMonth();
    String fecha = Año+"-"+Mes+"-"+Dia;
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){

            ArrayList<String> arrayRespuesta = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String hora_inicio, fecha, nombre, apellidos, prestacion;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    hora_inicio = jsonObject.getString("hora_inicio");
                    fecha = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                    apellidos = jsonObject.getString("apellidos");
                    prestacion = jsonObject.getString("prestacion");

                    int[] comprobarFecha = separarFecha(fecha);
                    if(comprobarFecha[0] == calendario.getYear() && comprobarFecha[1] == calendario.getMonth()+1 && comprobarFecha[2] == calendario.getDayOfMonth()){
                        arrayRespuesta.add(hora_inicio);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(nombre);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(apellidos);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(prestacion);
                    }
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }
            if(!arrayRespuesta.isEmpty()){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);
                tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.tabla_pacientes);
                agregarFila(arrayRespuesta);
            }else{
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, fecha, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Usuario.this);
    queue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

El método agregarFila es el siguiente, más abajo dentro de la misma clase (para hacerlo he usado la información de la siguiente pregunta: [Crear columnas de forma dinámica en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20180/crear-columnas-de-forma-din%C3%A1mica-en-un-tablelayout-de-android-studio)):

```
public void agregarFila(ArrayList<String> elementos){
    int num_cols = 4;
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    tablePaciente = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablePaciente);
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(this);
    for(int i=0; i<elementos.size(); i++){
        TextView texto = new TextView(this);
        texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
        texto.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
        fila.addView(texto);
        for (int j=0; j<num_cols; j++){
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tablePaciente.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
    tablePaciente.addView(fila);
}
```

Y el resultado que da el json es el siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "us_usuario": "DONATE",
        "us_clave": "DONATE",
        "hora_inicio": "14:00",
        "hora_fin": "14:15",
        "fecha": "2017-10-29",
        "nombre": "JACINTO",
        "apellidos": "JARAMILLO ROMERO",
        "prestacion": "FOTOCOAGULACION DR"
    },
    {
        "us_usuario": "DONATE",
        "us_clave": "DONATE",
        "hora_inicio": "18:20",
        "hora_fin": "18:35",
        "fecha": "2017-10-29",
        "nombre": "JUAN MANUEL",
        "apellidos": "LLORENTE RODRIGO",
        "prestacion": "REVISION OFTALMOLOGICA"
    }
]
```

Sin embargo, sólo me muestra la primera consulta, es decir, cuando selecciono la fecha del 29 de octubre, sólo me muestra los datos de JACINTO, tal como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer para que me muestren todas las consultas?

(Editado a partir de la respuesta de @A.Cedano)

A la hora de crear la clase RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario no me reconoce la clase RecyclerView.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de mi archivo Gradle es el siguiente (mi versión mínima es la 15 y la máxima es la 26)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tigestion.guillermo.prueba"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
}
```

¿Tengo que importar algo especial o hacer algo para que me reconozca el RecyclerView?

Vale, resuelto el error del RecyclerView, se resuelve haciendo Build->Clean Proyect y luego Build->Rebuild Proyect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android permite implementar [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419) para este tipo de operaciones. Su uso nos abre a todo un mundo de posibilidades que sería largo de explicar ahora, pero es algo en lo cual podrás profundizar más adelante.

Te haré una propuesta basada en esta metodología, sin detenerme demasiado en los detalles de cómo obtienes los datos.

### Paso 0: Configuración necesaria

`RecyclerView` es parte de la librería de soporte V7. Para que funcione, es necesario agregar esta dependencia en el archivo `app/build.gradle`.  No hay que agregar otro apartado `dependencies`, sino buscar ese apartado y poner en esta línea: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'` (la versión podría ser mayor en un futuro, usa siempre la última versión).

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Para más detalles de la compatibilidad [se puede consultar este enlace de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html?hl=es-419).

### Paso 1:

Llamaremos a la actividad donde quieres mostrar la tabla `TablaActivity` .

Vamos a crear un layout `activity_tabla` que contendrá el `RecyclerView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TablaActivity"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_usuarios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### Paso 2

Creamos un layout que contendrá las diferentes columnas de la tabla. En este ejemplo tendremos un layout con dos columnas. Le llamaremos `table_layout`. Se trata de dos `textView` dentro de un `linearlayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstColumn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondColumn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Paso 3:

Vamos a crear un modelo de datos.

Los modelos de datos son una práctica muy recomendada. Generalmente un modelo de datos representa una entidad completa de nuestra aplicación, por ejemplo, una tabla de la base de datos.

La comodidad de manejar modelos de datos es impresionante en cualquier caso, por ejemplo, con la librería Gson tú podrías obtener tus objetos JSON dentro del modelo de datos `Usuario` directamente.

Para los `RecyclerView` veremos también su importancia y la claridad que aportan al código.

Imaginemos un modelo de datos simple... Luego lo puedes adaptar.

```
public class Usuario {
    private String strNombre;
    private String strApellido;
    private int intId;

    public Usuario(int id, String nombre,  String apellido) {
        strNombre = nombre;
        strApellido = apellido;
        intId=id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return intId;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return strNombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return strApellido;
    }
}
```

Este modelo tendrá todos los métodos que quieras, de forma que lo uses para todo lo que sea relativo a usuarios.

---

### Paso 4:

Crearemos un adaptador que hará de intermediario entre el `RecyclerView` y nuestro modelo de datos:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ViewHolder> {
    protected RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ItemListener mListener;
    ArrayList<Usuario> mValues;
    Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> values, RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ItemListener itemListener) {

        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener = itemListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        /*Aquí ponemos el table_layout del Paso 2*/
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.table_layout, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick(Usuario item);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView;
        public TextView textView2;
        public View layout;
        Usuario item;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);
            layout = v;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView = v.findViewById(R.id.firstColumn);
            textView2 = v.findViewById(R.id.secondColumn);
        }

        public void setData(Usuario item) {
            this.item = item;
            /*Aquí usamos las propiedades del modelo de datos*/
            textView.setText(item.getNombre());
            textView2.setText(item.getApellido());

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Paso 5:

**¡Al fin!** Ahora viene lo bueno.

Nótese que todo lo anterior es algo que tendremos fijo en nuestra App. Ahora vamos a cosechar las ventajas de haber trabajado tanto.

Este sería un modelo de `TablaActivity`, la actividad principal que mencionaba en el **Paso 1**. Aunque este código lo podemos implementar desde cualquier otra parte de la App donde necesitemos manejar instancias de la clase `Usuario` presentándolos en una tabla.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ItemListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TablaActivity";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Usuario> arrayList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabla);

        /*
         *Aquí nosotros podemos usar un JSON
         *o lo que deseemos para llenar el array
         *con objetos Usuario
        */

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new Usuario(1,"Pedro", "Pérez"));
        arrayList.add(new Usuario(2,"Santiago", "González"));
        arrayList.add(new Usuario(3,"Juan", "Cedano"));

        /*Pasamos datos del array al recycler*/

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_usuarios);

        RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario(this, arrayList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

        /*
         *He aquí uno, entre muchos otros aspectos interesantes
         *Podremos obtener cualquier dato del usuario, 
         *aunque no lo tengamos a la vista
         *aquí por ejemplo, el id
         *El método onItemClick nos permitiría por ejemplo mostrar
         *más detalles del usuario específico sobre el cual hemos clickeado
         *o mostrar un CardView con una ficha completa de ese usuario, etc.
        */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Usuario item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getId() + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

---

El resultado es una tabla de usuarios... y al hacer click en cualquiera de ellos se muestra su id en la tostadora.

Este código se puede adaptar, por ejemplo para mostrar más detalles de un usuario en específico al hacer clic sobre él, para mostrar un `CardView`,  para agregar o quitar usuarios de la tabla, etc.

Las posibilidades de esta forma de obtener y usar los datos son enormes.

---

### Enlaces:

Hay muchos tutoriales interesantes sobre el tema. He aquí algunos:

- [Tutorial Para Crear Un RecyclerView Junto A CardViews En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-cardview/)
- [Listas dinámicas en Android usando RecyclerView y CardView](https://programacionymas.com/blog/listas-dinamicas-android-usando-recycler-view-card-view)
- [Empezando con RecyclerView y CardView en Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)
- [Using lists and grids in Android with RecyclerView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

Comment: Tengo un problema con el RecyclerView, mi android no lo reconoce. ¿Alguna versión concreta que tenga que tener para trabajar con él?

Comment: Necesitarás como mínimo la v7, API 21. [Aquí está toda la información](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html?hl=es-419).

Comment: He editado la pregunta para mostrar mi gradle y el tipo de error que me da, por si he escrito algo mal sin darme cuenta.

Comment: Vale, ahora me funciona tu código, voy a intentar adaptarlo a mi programa

Comment: @G.Corporales debes agregar esta línea en el apartado `dependencies` del gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'`

Comment: Vale, ya lo he adaptado a mi código y funciona, muchas gracias.