# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos de una tabla de sql server en un RecyclerView de Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Miren... he estado desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio que pueda mostrar mensajes desde una base de datos en Sql Server. Ya tengo mi base de datos en MS SQL Server, mi rest api hecho en visual studio... y un código en Android Studio. Quisiera visualizar el contenido de una tabla en un RecyclerView & CardView. Hay algo que pueda hacer? Aquí está mi código de mi API en Visual Studio c#.

```
    public class Publicacion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Departamento { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Enlace { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public string CorreoElectronico { get; set; }
}
    interface IServiceAPI
{
    DataTable ObtenerPublicacion();
}
    public class ServiceAPI :IServiceAPI
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection;

    public ServiceAPI()
    {
        dbConnection = DBConnect.getConnection();
    }      
    public DataTable ObtenerPublicacion()
    {
        DataTable deptTable = new DataTable();
        deptTable.Columns.Add("departamento", typeof(String));
        deptTable.Columns.Add("descripcion", typeof(String));
        deptTable.Columns.Add("enlace", typeof(String));
        deptTable.Columns.Add("fecha", typeof(String));
        deptTable.Columns.Add("correoElectronico", typeof(String));

        if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }

        string query = "SELECT top 70 * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY fecha DESC;";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                deptTable.Rows.Add(reader["departamento"], reader["descripcion"], reader["enlace"], reader["fecha"], reader["correoElectronico"]);
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
        dbConnection.Close();

        return deptTable;

    }
}
```

Este es el de mi Android Studio

```
    public class PublicacionModelo
    {
       private String departamento,descripcion,enlace,correo;
       private String fecha;
       private int foto;

public PublicacionModelo(String departamento, String descripcion, String enlace, String fecha,String correo) {
    super();
    this.departamento = departamento;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.enlace = enlace;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.correo = correo;
}

public PublicacionModelo()
{
    super();
    this.departamento=null;
    this.descripcion = null;
    this.enlace = null;
    this.fecha = null;
    this.correo = null;
}

public String getDepartamento() { return departamento; }

public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
    this.departamento = departamento;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getEnlace() {
    return enlace;
}

public void setEnlace(String enlace) {
    this.enlace = enlace;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getCorreo(){ return correo; }

public void setCorreo(String correo) { this.correo = correo; }

    }

     //El adaptador...
     public class RecyclerViewAdaptador1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdaptador1.ViewHolder>
    {
     private TextView Email;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private TextView departamento,descripcion,enlace,fecha,correo;
    CardView cv;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvAlumno);
        departamento = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDepartamento1);
        descripcion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDescripcion1);
        enlace = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblEnlace1);
        fecha = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblFecha1);
        correo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblCorreo1);
        correo.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }

}
    public List<PublicacionModelo> alumnoLista;
public RecyclerViewAdaptador1(List<PublicacionModelo> alumnoLista)
{

    this.alumnoLista=alumnoLista;
}
     @Override
public RecyclerViewAdaptador1.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_alumno, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewAdaptador1.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewAdaptador1.ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdaptador1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PublicacionModelo publicacion = alumnoLista.get(position);

    holder.departamento.setText(publicacion.getDepartamento());
    holder.descripcion.setText(publicacion.getDescripcion());
    holder.enlace.setText(publicacion.getEnlace());
    holder.fecha.setText(publicacion.getFecha());
    holder.correo.setText(publicacion.getCorreo());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alumnoLista.size();
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
              }

 //Código del activity
      package com.example.juanisaid.itnlapp2;

      import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.net.Uri;
      import android.os.AsyncTask;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.StrictMode;
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
      import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.Toast;

      import org.json.JSONObject;

      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
      import java.sql.ResultSet;
      import java.sql.SQLException;
      import java.sql.Statement;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;

      public class AlumnoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private RecyclerView recyclerViewPublicacion1;
      private RecyclerViewAdaptador1 adaptadorPublicacion1;
      private Button EnviarCorreo;
      Context context; 

      List<PublicacionModelo> dataListAlumno;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alumno);



    dataListAlumno = new ArrayList<PublicacionModelo>();
    new AsyncMostrarPublicacion().execute();
    recyclerViewPublicacion1=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.ReciclerPublicacion1);
    //recyclerViewPublicacion1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewPublicacion1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adaptadorPublicacion1 = new RecyclerViewAdaptador1(dataListAlumno);
    recyclerViewPublicacion1.setAdapter(adaptadorPublicacion1);


    EnviarCorreo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarCorreo);




         }
    protected class AsyncMostrarPublicacion extends AsyncTask<Void, 
    JSONObject, List<PublicacionModelo>>
    {
    @Override
    protected List<PublicacionModelo> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
       List<PublicacionModelo> alumnoModelo = null;
       RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
       try {

           JSONObject jsonObj = api.ObtenerPublicacion();
           JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
           alumnoModelo=parser.parseDept(jsonObj);

           } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Log.d("AsyncMostrarPublicacion", e.getMessage());
          }
          return alumnoModelo;
           }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<PublicacionModelo> alumnoModelos) {
    super.onPostExecute(alumnoModelos);
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnoModelos.size(); i++)
    {

        dataListAlumno.add(new PublicacionModelo(alumnoModelos.get(i).getDepartamento(), alumnoModelos.get(i).getDescripcion(), alumnoModelos.get(i).getEnlace(), alumnoModelos.get(i).getFecha(), alumnoModelos.get(i).getCorreo()));
    }
    }
    }
    }
     //Clase JSONParser
     public class JSONParser {

public JSONParser()
{
    super();
}

public List<PublicacionModelo> parseDept(JSONObject object)
{
    List<PublicacionModelo> arrayList= new ArrayList<PublicacionModelo>();
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("Value");
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            //String departamento, String descripcion, String enlace,                                                                     String fecha, int foto
            jsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayList.add(new PublicacionModelo(jsonObj.getString("departamento"), jsonObj.getString("descripcion"),jsonObj.getString("enlace")/*,jsonObj.getInt("foto")*/,jsonObj.getString("fecha"),jsonObj.getString("correoElectronico")));
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("JSONParser => parseDept", e.getMessage());
    }
    return arrayList;
}
}
```

Clase RestApi (También de Android Studio)

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class RestAPI {
    private final String urlString = "http://10.10.21.61/JSONWebAPI4/Handler1.ashx";

    private static String convertStreamToUTF8String(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            int readedChars = 0;
            while (readedChars != -1) {
                readedChars = reader.read(buffer);
                if (readedChars > 0)
                   sb.append(buffer, 0, readedChars);
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


    private String load(String contents) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        w.write(contents);
        w.flush();
        InputStream istream = conn.getInputStream();
        String result = convertStreamToUTF8String(istream);
        return result;
        }


    private Object mapObject(Object o) {
        Object finalValue = null;
        if (o.getClass() == String.class) {
        finalValue = o;
        }
        else if (Number.class.isInstance(o)) {
        finalValue = String.valueOf(o);
    } else if (Date.class.isInstance(o)) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Locale("en", "USA"));
        finalValue = sdf.format((Date)o);
    }
    else if (Collection.class.isInstance(o)) {
        Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) o;
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
        for (Object item : col) {
            jarray.put(mapObject(item));
        }
        finalValue = jarray;
    } else {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Method[] methods = o.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getDeclaringClass() == o.getClass()
                    && method.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC
                    && method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                String key = method.getName().substring(3);
                try {
                    Object obj = method.invoke(o, null);
                    Object value = mapObject(obj);
                    map.put(key, value);
                    finalValue = new JSONObject(map);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return finalValue;
}
    public JSONObject ObtenerPublicacion() throws Exception {
        JSONObject result = null;
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
        o.put("interface","RestAPI");
        o.put("method", "ObtenerPublicacion");
        o.put("parameters", p);
        String s = o.toString();
        String r = load(s);
        result = new JSONObject(r);
        return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sería largo de explicar. [Esta respuesta te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967). He tratado de explicarlo paso a paso. Saludos.

Comment: Viendo tu enlace de respuesta me genero otra pregunta ¿Los adaptadores del recyclerView suelen recibir datos de tipo ArrayList<modelo> o List<Modelo>?

Comment: `List` es una interfaz, no es una clase. De modo que puedes usar `List` si lo deseas... pero al final tendrás que recurrir a `ArrayList` de todos modos. Si tú usas `List`, cuando tengas que llenar los datos, en la activity donde lo vayas a hacer te tocará: (1). hacer `import` tanto de `java.util.ArrayList;` como de `java.util.List;`  (2). declarar el miembro de la clase que usarás para poner las instancias de tu modelo así: `private List<Modelo> modeloList = new ArrayList<>();` ... como puedes ver al final, terminas usando un `ArrayList`, porque no puedes crear una instancia de `List`

Comment: Ok. Gracias. Seguiré investigando...