# RecyclerView que lleve a diferentes actividades

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Lo que tengo es: Un recyclerview con Imágenes que de diferentes lugares como bares, cafeterías, etc.

Lo que quiero es: Que cuando haga click encima de de cada una de estas imagenes me lleven a un activity diferente ( al activity del lugar correspondiente )

Mi pregunta es: Cómo puedo hacer que esto suceda? He buscado en múltiples lugares y aún no hayo respuesta, por favor, agradecería mucho las respuestas con ejemplos de código dado que aún no soy muy bueno programando, gracias de antemano

Mi adaptador

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
private View.OnClickListener listener;
Context context;//borrar

public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listaLugares) {
    listalugares = listaLugares;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//esto es lo que hacereferencia al xml donde vamos a meter la info
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);//aqui le asignamos el valor del view al viewHolder
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {// este metodo es el que se encarga de establecer la conexion entre el adaptador y la clase Viewholder ( a la cual le asignamos el xml)
    holder.etiLugares.setText(listalugares.get(position).getLugares());// asi se asignan los textos
    holder.Foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());//asi se asignan las fotos

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {//este metodo va a decir el tamaño del viewHolder, en este caso de tamaño del array listalugares
    return listalugares.size();//se hace asi
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    if(listener!= null){
        listener.onClick(view);
   }
```

}

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView etiLugares;
    ImageView Foto;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        etiLugares = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);//esto hace referencia a los elementos donde queremos meter la info
        Foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Juan bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Yo tengo un `RecyclerView` que hace exactamente eso. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967) yo he explicado paso por paso toda la implementación, desde el principio. La parte interesante para lo que quieres es este método `public void onItemClick(Usuario item) {` que se encuentra en el **Paso 5** de la respuesta. Allí `item`  es una instancia de la clase que usas como modelo, y puedes obtener las opciones del menú mediante un método de esa clase, por ejemplo `item.getId()` y usar un `switch` para llamar cada `Activity` con `Intent`.

Comment: Un millón de gracias por su respuesta, ahora mismo voy a donde usted me indica, llevo dias estancado , una vez más, muchas gracias

Comment: En la respuesta yo explico un `ReclycerView` sin imágenes, por lo que digo al principio sobre el `Layout` lo puedes ignorar. En el **paso 5** yo muestro cómo obtener datos, cualquier dato, del modelo (`User`)  en este caso. Como estás pasando una instancia del modelo de datos, puedes obtener cualquier dato mediante métodos que existan en la clase que uses como modelo de datos, que en tu caso serían las diferentes opciones de las Activitys a invocar.

Comment: Le agradezco mucho que haya mostrado interés en mi pregunta, pero sigo un poco perdido, en el caso de aue solamente le quisiera poner el Intent a la primera foto del RecyclerView, como lo haria?? por favor, si es tan amable, apreciaria mucho un ejemplo de código, una vez más, muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora mismo no puedo ayudarte. Lo dejo en el tintero para más tarde. Se trataría de tener un modelo de datos con las diferentes opciones que quieres y cuando se de click a cualquiera de los elementos del RecyclerView obtener el dato del elemento clickeado mediante un getter que debes tener en tu modelo. Cuando hablo de modelo, hablo de una `Clase` de Java como cualquier otra. Cuando pueda te pongo un ejemplo completo.

Comment: Un millón de gracias amigo, le agradezco mucho su paciencia e interés, estaré a la espera

Comment: Pudiste solucionar esto?

Comment: Si, al final pude solucionarlo estas interesado en la respuesta??