# Ordenar ListView alfabéticamente

Tags: android, android-listview

tengo un listview que me muestra personas de una base de datos SQLserver, entonces me gustaría ordenar esta lista que me muestra alfabéticamente, alguien me podría poner un ejemplo claro y si puede ser a raíz de mi listview sobre cómo hacer esto? Pongo el código del listview, gracias!

```
public class Listado extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
TextView idtext;
EditText etFiltrar;
String where = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    setupActionBAR();
    etFiltrar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFiltrrar);

    etFiltrar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            where = etFiltrar.getText().toString();
            mostrarClientes();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMostrar);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            idtext = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.id);
            Log.i("Click", position + " " + idtext.getText());

        }
    });
    mostrarClientes();
}



public void mostrarClientes() {
    HashMap<String, String> clientes = new HashMap<>();
    ConectarHaciaSQL consql;
    consql = new ConectarHaciaSQL();
    Connection cn = consql.conexionBD();

    try {
        Statement pst = cn.createStatement();
        String sel;
        sel = "select CLI.idcliente, CLI.NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 from clientes as CLI" + " left join ubicacionesClientes as UC on UC.idcliente = CLI.idCliente ";
        if (where != "") {
            sel = sel + " where CLI.NombreComercial like '%" + where + "%'";

        }
        //readData();
        //sel = sel + " ORDER BY CLI.idcliente ASC";
        //Ejecuta el query del SQL
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sel);
        //Recorre la tabla del SQL
        while (rs.next()) {
            clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));//
        }

        if (rs != null) {
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No hay nada ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();

        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_items,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

        Iterator it = clientes.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultMap);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("Error", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué no traes la lista ya ordenada aplicando un `ORDER BY` en la instrucción SQL?

Comment: Otra cosa que recomendaría sería que apliques consultas preparadas en tu código para evitar posibles ataques de **Inyección SQL**, pues tu código, tal y como está escrito ahora es altamente vulnerable. Un usuario mal intencionado podría fácilmente borrar, cambiar o insertar datos no deseados en tu base de datos con una facilidad pasmosa... e incluso podría acceder a otras áreas de tu sistema modificando maliciosamente el contenido de la variable `where`, la cual es recogida desde una fuente que depende del usuario y la cual tú mandas a ejecutar sin ningún control.

Comment: Hola, pues cuando traigo la consulta ya ordenada con ORDER BY como tu dices, no me hace nada realmente.., miraré tu recomendación de inyección SQL

Comment: Borja debería traerla ordenada, a no ser que hagas luego alguna manipulación de los datos que los desordene de nuevo. Claro está, en el `ORDER BY` debes poner las columnas por las que quieres ordenar, sabiendo que puedes usar más de una columna separadas por coma. En cuanto al otro tema, la aplicación de consultas preparadas blindarará el código contra riesgos de Inyección y también optimizará la consulta en sí.

Comment: Hecho está y nada... seguro que es una tontería, yo también me extrañé cuando no me ordenaba si lo traigo ordenado de la consulta

Comment: La verdad es que no podría decirte más, habría que detenerse un poco a entender la lógica de tu programa y por qué usas el `HashMap`, el `Adapter`, por qué iteras sobre los elementos, etc. En cualquier caso, no sé si sabes que `ListView` ha sido superado por **`RecyclerView`**. Es un elemento más eficiente, y con suma facilidad puedes mostrar los elementos en el orden en que estos ingresan. [Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo de implementación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967) por si te interesa. Podría parecer largo, pero cuando logras configurarlo, vas sobre ruedas...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando la sentencia SQL que utilizas, ordenandolo directamente ahí, es decir, crea la sentencia select de la siguiente forma:

```
    sel = "select CLI.idcliente, CLI.NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 from clientes as CLI" + " left join ubicacionesClientes as UC on UC.idcliente = CLI.idCliente ";
    if (where != "") {
        sel = sel + " where CLI.NombreComercial like '%" + where + "%'";

    }

    sel= sel + "ORDER BY CLI.NombreComercial";
```

Suponiendo que lo quieres ordenar por NombreComercial.