# ListView personalizado con base de datos solo muestra un dato Android

Tags: android, base-de-datos, android-listview

Estoy realizando una aplicación que debe imprimir una lista de tareas, las tareas las obtendrá de la base de datos, utilizando un ListView personalizado con un TextView y un CheckBox. El problema viene cuando imprimo los tareas extraídas de la base de datos solo imprime 1 de las tareas la ultima, ya que si ingreso mas tareas al actualizar solo muestra la recién ingresada. Les dejo los codigos, espero puedan ayudarme

```
//MainActivity.java
package com.example.hermanos.basededatos;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
public DatosAdapter adapter;
Datos datos[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    Basededatos n_user = new Basededatos(this,"Registro",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = n_user.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql="SELECT * FROM tareas";
    Cursor registros= bd.rawQuery(sql,null);
    if(registros.moveToFirst()){
        while(registros.moveToNext()){
            datos= new Datos[]{new Datos(registros.getString(1))};
        }
    }
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header_row,null);
    lv.addHeaderView(header);
    adapter = new DatosAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row,datos);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void n_user(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}


//Datos.java
package com.example.hermanos.basededatos;

public class Datos {

        public String tarea;

        /*public Datos(){
            super();
        }*/

        public Datos(String tarea){
            super();
            this.tarea = tarea;
        }
}
//DatosAdapter.java
package com.example.hermanos.basededatos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datos> {

    Context mycontext;
    int mylayout_resourseID;
    Datos mydata[] = null;

    public DatosAdapter(Context context,int layout_resourseID, Datos[] data){

        super(context,layout_resourseID,data);

        this.mycontext = context;
        this.mylayout_resourseID = layout_resourseID;
        this.mydata = data;

        }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        Datosholder holder = null;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mycontext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mylayout_resourseID,parent,false);
            holder = new Datosholder();
            holder.textview = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Datosholder)row.getTag();
        }

        Datos datos = mydata[position];
        holder.textview.setText(datos.tarea);

        return row;
    }

    static class Datosholder{
        TextView textview;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sólo como comentario, para que no gastes demasiado esfuerzo tratando de hacer funcionar tu `ListView`, debes saber que existe otro componente que es más recomendado que `ListView`, debido a su rendimiento y a su facilidad de manejo una vez tienes los diferentes elementos necesarios. Me refiero a `RecyclerView`. Te recomiendo que aprendas a manejarlo y cuando lo domines te vas a olvidar de los `ListView`, `TableView` y demás. [Puedes consultar esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967) y los enlaces que hay al final de la misma.

Comment: Ya como solución a este caso concreto, puedes crear un arraylist del tipo `Dato` así: `List<Dato> lstDatos = new ArrayList<Dato>();` para luego llenarlo dentro del `while` de este modo: `lstDatos.add(new Datos(registros.getString(1)));`  Y luego lo pasas al adapter: `adapter = new DatosAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row,lstDatos);` El problema es la forma en que llenas la lista en el `while`.

Comment: Gracias por la idea del RecyclerView ya lo probare. La solución que me diste me da un error que decia "List cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)". Lo logre resolver de la solamente modificando esto al principio Datos datos[]= new Datos[15]; y un contador en el while. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en realidad **estas agregando un solo elemento en el `array` datos**, al final solo tendrías un valor el cual se esta mostrando en tu ListView:

```
  if(registros.moveToFirst()){
        while(registros.moveToNext()){
            datos= new Datos[]{new Datos(registros.getString(1))};
        }
    }
```

En realidad lo que debes hacer es un array de elementos tipo `Datos` y agregar dentro los valores obtenidos del cursor.

```
 ...
 ...
 Cursor registros= bd.rawQuery(sql,null);

 //Crea arraylist de objetos tipo Datos.
 List datos = new ArrayList<Datos>();

    if(registros.moveToFirst()){
        while(registros.moveToNext()){
            //datos= new Datos[]{new Datos(registros.getString(1))};

             //Agrega valores al arrayList.
             datos.add(registros.getString(1));
        }
    }
 ...
 ...
```

ahora también debes cambiar tu `Adapter` para que acepte esta lista de elementos y muestre el valor de `tarea` de cada objeto:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DatosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datos> {

    Context mycontext;
    int mylayout_resourseID;
   //Datos mydata[] = null;
    List mydata;

    public DatosAdapter(Context context, int layout_resourseID, List data){

        super(context,layout_resourseID,data);

        this.mycontext = context;
        this.mylayout_resourseID = layout_resourseID;
        this.mydata = data;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        Datosholder holder = null;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mycontext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mylayout_resourseID,parent,false);
            holder = new Datosholder();
            holder.textview = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Datosholder)row.getTag();
        }

        //Datos datos = mydata[position];
        String tarea = mydata.get(position).toString();
        //holder.textview.setText(datos.tarea);
        holder.textview.setText(tarea);

        return row;
    }

    static class Datosholder{
        TextView textview;
    }

}
```