# Llenar un ListView datos complejos con adaptador

Tags: android, listview, cursor

Soy nuevo en Android Studio y estoy intentando llenar un ListView con objetos y el problema es que todos los tutoriales que sigo me llevan al mismo fallo, no puedo llamar a los métodos que deberían permitirme modificar los textos en el layout.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdaptadorNoticias extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList datos;


    public AdaptadorNoticias(Context context, ArrayList datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitemnoticias, datos);
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
};

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemnoticias, null);


        TextView titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.prueba);
        titulo.setText(datos.get(position).getNombre());//Aquí da error.

        TextView nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.prueba2);
        nombre.setText(datos.get(position).getNombre());//Aquí da error.

        return item;
    }


}
```

Gracias.

Comment: verifica que los elementos retornados no sean **NULL**.  No has comentado que error te da, pero supongo que debe ser una excepción de acceso a valor `null`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que Android propone una alternartiva superior a `ListView`, se trata de `RecyclerView`. Si te interesa, [aquí tienes una respuesta paso a paso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967) basada en `RecyclerView` que puede ayudarte a resolver el problema con código optimizado. La respuesta incluye además un *listener* para los clicks de los elementos individuales, en caso de querer mostrar más info basada en cada fila de la lista (esto es opcional, dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer).

Comment: El error es básicamente que no puedo llamar al método .getNombre(), no entiende "datos" como si fuera una instanciación del objeto, a pesar de estar así en todos los ejemplos que he visto. El tema del RecyclerView lo he mirado pero es aún más complejo y me daba el mismo error en el adaptador. Gracias.

Comment: Normal que no lo entienda, has creado el `ArrayList` sin especificar el tipo de datos que va a contener, con lo que o haces cast cada vez que usas un objeto del array o defines el `ArrayList` bien: `private ArrayList<Como_sea_que_se_llame_la_clase_de_los_datos> datos;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te he comentado en un comentario, el problema es que el compilador no sabe de qué tipo son los datos guardados en el `ArrayList`, así que no puedes hacer `datos.get(position).getNombre()`, porque no sabe que los objetos del `ArrayList` son de una clase que tiene un método llamado `getNombre()`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
public class AdaptadorNoticias extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<TuClaseQueNoSeComoSeLlama> datos;


    public AdaptadorNoticias(Context context, ArrayList<TuClaseQueNoSeComoSeLlama> datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitemnoticias, datos);
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
};

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemnoticias, null);

        TuClaseQueNoSeComoSeLlama objeto = datos.get(position);
        TextView titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.prueba);
        titulo.setText(objeto.getNombre());//Aquí da error.

        TextView nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.prueba2);
        nombre.setText(objeto.getNombre());//Aquí da error.

        return item;
    }


}
```

También he hecho un cambio para obtener el objeto del `ArrayList` solo una vez, y no una vez por cada campo. Si tienes muchos elementos en el `ArrayList`, no es lo más óptimo hacerle buscar el objeto cada vez.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora si funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

> El error es básicamente que no puedo llamar al método .getNombre(), no
>   entiende "datos" como si fuera una instanciación del objeto, a pesar
>   de estar así en todos los ejemplos que he visto.

Esto se debe a que tienes un `ArrayList`  de objetos pero en este caso debes realizar un "casting", debes verificar que tipo de objeto estas almacenando en el  `ArrayList`.

> **Casting** : significa tomar un Objeto de un tipo particular y
>   convertirlo en otro tipo de Objeto, debes considerar que en Java no
>   puede convertir ninguna variable a ningún tipo aleatorio.

Por ejemplo suponiendo un objeto llamado "`Producto`" debes realizar un casting de esta forma para obtener el valor de su propiedad:

```
 titulo.setText(((Producto)objeto).getNombre());
```