# Como asociar una URL a un array que tengo creado con su posición

Tags: android

Lo que intento es poder cargar una URL en un array que ya existe para poder mostrar al presionar el botón de esa posición, me logre abrir la web de ese enlace.

Tengo un `fragment` que pasa datos a una actividad que muestra una imagen de un libro y el nombre de autor y al hacer clic me abre otra actividad para mostrar el detalle del libro.

Necesito que al hacer clic en el botón que cree para cada fila al hacer clic me abra la URL de cada posición del array.

Quisiera saber si es posible.

#### Clase Adaptador:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    Context contexto;
    String[][] datos;
    int[] datosImg;
    String[][] urls;

    public Adaptador(Context conexto , String[][] datos , int[] imagenes)
    {
        this.contexto = conexto;
        this.datos = datos;
        this.datosImg = imagenes;
        

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)conexto.getSystemService(conexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);

        TextView nombrelibro = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvnombrelibro);

        TextView autor = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvautor);

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivlibros);

        RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

        nombrelibro.setText(datos[i][0]);
        autor.setText(datos[i][1]);
        imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);

        calificacion.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[i][2]));


        imagen.setTag(i);

        imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent visorImagen = new Intent(contexto, VisorImagen.class);
                visorImagen.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[(Integer)v.getTag()]);

                contexto.startActivity(visorImagen);

            }
        });


        return vista;
    }
```

#### Fragment Libros:

```
public class  GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lista;
    private Button botonvisitar;

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvgaleria);
        botonvisitar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botonvisitar);

        final String[][] datos = {
                {"EL JUEGO DE RIPPER", "ISABEL ALLENDE", "9", " Tal como predijo la astróloga más reputada de San Francisco, una oleada de crímenes comienza a sacudir la ciudad. En la investigación sobre los asesinatos, el inspector Bob Martín recibirá la ayuda inesperada de un grupo de internautas especializados en juegos de rol, Ripper.«“Mi madre todavía está viva, pero la matará el Viernes Santo a medianoche”, le advirtió Amanda Martín al inspector jefe y éste no lo puso en duda, porque la chica había dado pruebas de saber más que él y todos sus colegas del Departamento de Homicidios. La mujer estaba cautiva en algún punto de los dieciocho mil kilómetros cuadrados de la bahía de San Francisco, tenían pocas horas para encontrarla con vida y él no sabía por dónde empezar a buscarla ", "www.google.com.uy"},
                {"ONCE MINUTOS", "PAULO COELHO", "7", "Once minutos es un libro que explora la naturaleza del sexo y del amor, la intensa y difícil relación entre cuerpo y alma, y cómo alcanzar la perfecta unión entre ambos. Once Minutos ofrece al lector una experiencia inigualable de lectura y reflexión.", "www.google.com.uy"},
                {"APRENDE A PROGRAMAR JUGANDO", "HOSTGATOR", "8", "Aprender programación puede ser más entretenido y atractivo si la técnica incluye jugar videogames, ¿no es cierto? Esta didáctica de aprendizaje funciona tanto para jóvenes como adultos. Por eso aquí te contamos las mejores opciones para aprender a programar de forma entretenida.", "www.google.com.uy"},
                {"CURSO ANDROID", "MAESTROS DEL WEB", "7", "¿Quieres aprender todo sobre Android y no sabes por dónde iniciar? Hoy empezamos un Curso de Android donde te llevaremos paso a paso por elementos básicos, ejemplos prácticos y descargas de código sobre esta popular plataforma móvil de Google.", "www.google.com.uy"},

        };



        int[] datosImg = {R.drawable.isabelayende, R.drawable.onceminutospaulocoelho, R.drawable.programar, R.drawable.libroandroid};


        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvListaGaleria);


        lista.setAdapter(new Adaptador(getActivity(), datos, datosImg));

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetallePelicula.class);
                visorDetalles.putExtra("TIT", datos[position][0]);
                visorDetalles.putExtra("DET", datos[position][3]);


                startActivity(visorDetalles);
            }
        });



        botonvisitar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(urls.toString()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

Probé agregar la URL al final del array datos, pero no logro que muestre bien.

Comment: exactamente, cual es tu error?

Comment: si lo que quieres es concatenar cadenas de caracteres, entonces usa +, si lo que quieres es añadir una url, entonces tienes que usar un objeto para ello apropiado

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No estaría de más que aclarases el lenguaje que estás usando añadiéndolo como etiqueta en la pregunta.

Comment: No se ve con claridad dónde está tu problema ¿? Lo que más dificultad causa, creo yo, es que no tienes el código bien organizado. Para trabajar con adaptadores es más simple tener una clase en este caso `Libro` con todas las propiedades del mismo: `titulo, autor, url` etc. Luego llenas el adaptador con objetos de la clase `Libro` con todas sus propiedades y si necesitas alguna de ellas la obtienes en el `onclick`. [Aquí hay un ejemplo completo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967) basado en `RecyclerView` y una clase `Usuario` que cambiarías por la clase `Libro`.

Comment: Muchas a todos, disculpen por no expresarme de forma correcta, necesitaba que al mostrar una actividad me permitiera recibir una url ya cargada de ante mano, lo que hice fue agregar una url al array string que ya tenia y pasarla por parametro a la actividad nueva. Luego la cargue en un textview y con el evento onclick logre que abriera la web con un intent. Solucionado gracias a todos