# Por que no me recupera foto de firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

llevo dias intentando recuperar la foto de perfil desde firebase y no es posible. De la unica manera que me funciona es que cargando la foto con Glide pero me recupera la de la cuenta de google, y yo quisiera recuperar la foto que sube el usuario a firebase. Subire ambos codigos, el que me funciona con google y el que intento recuperar de firebase pero me da error.

Adapter (Firebase) :

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

private Context ctx;
Message message;
private final String TAG = "demoMessageAdapter";
private ChatActivity dataUpdateAfterMessageDelete;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ArrayList<Message> messageObjects;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
private Date convertedDate;
private String date;
private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
private String currentUserId;
int num = 1;


MessagesAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Message> objects, ChatActivity chatActivity) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.messageObjects = (ArrayList<Message>) objects;
    this.dataUpdateAfterMessageDelete = chatActivity;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


}


@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileimage");
    message = getItem(position);
    MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messages_listview, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.messageTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTV);
        viewHolder.messageSenderTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageSenderTV);
        viewHolder.messageTimeTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTimeTV);
        viewHolder.fotoforos = convertView.findViewById(R.id.fotoforos);
        viewHolder.deleteMessageButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteMessageButton);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (!message.user_id.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid())) {
        viewHolder.deleteMessageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.deleteMessageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    viewHolder.messageSenderTV.setText(message.user_name);
    viewHolder.messageTV.setText(message.message);
    if (message != null) {
        String profileimage = UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("profileimage").getRef().toString();
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(profileimage).placeholder(R.drawable.profilefoto).into(viewHolder.fotoforos);
    } else {
        viewHolder.fotoforos.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profilefoto));
    }
```

ChatActivity (firebase)

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    setTitle("Chatroom");

    threadNameTV = findViewById(R.id.threadNameTV);
    newMessageET = findViewById(R.id.newMessageET);
    homeButton = findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    messagesLV = findViewById(R.id.messagesLV);
    final View messageview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.messages_listview, null);
    messageTV = messageview.findViewById(R.id.messageTV);
    fotoforos = messageview.findViewById(R.id.fotoforos);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileimage");
    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ChatActivity.this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);


    threadNameTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("messageThreadDetails")) {
            messageThread = (MessageThread) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("messageThreadDetails");
            threadNameTV.setText(messageThread.title);
            getMessages(messageThread.thread_id);
            incrementar();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (user != null) {
                user = null;
                mDatabase = null;
                mAuth = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ThreadsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                user = null;
                mDatabase = null;
                mAuth = null;
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "You need to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, IniciarSesion.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = newMessageET.getText().toString();
            String user_name = user.getDisplayName();
            String profileimage = UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("profileimage").getRef().toString();
            Picasso.with(ChatActivity.this).load(profileimage).placeholder(R.drawable.profilefoto).into(fotoforos);
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Enter Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                addMessage(message, user_name, profileimage, messageThread.thread_id);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
    at com.example.ayurveda2.normas.MessagesAdapter.getView(MessagesAdapter.java:120)
```

Adapter (funciona y carga foto de google)

```
if (message != null) {
        Glide.with(ctx).load(message.getProfileimage()).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(viewHolder.fotoforos);
    } else {
        viewHolder.fotoforos.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profilefoto));
    }
```

Chat Activity (funciona y carga foto de google)

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = newMessageET.getText().toString();
            String user_name = user.getDisplayName();
            String profileimage = UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("profileimage").getRef().toString();
            Glide.with(ChatActivity.this).load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(fotoforos);
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Enter Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                addMessage(message, user_name, profileimage, messageThread.thread_id);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Las llamadas a Firebase son asíncronas, entonces, debes recuperar los datos que vienen de Firebase dentro de algún listener y dentro de ese bloque llenar el objeto donde necesites esos datos.

Comment: habria que hacer el listener desde el adapter y chat activity? o con uno alcanza?

Comment: Para no liarte demasiado con esto sería preferible trabajar con una clase, a la cual le pasas los datos y luego usas esa clase para llenar la vista. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967). Es sobre otro tema, pero muestra una forma de trabajar en la que la información que iría en el `RecyclerView` es tomada de una instancia de la clase `Usuario`. Dado que es facilísimo mapear un resultado de Firebase a una clase, podrías llenar una sola vez la instancia de la clase (desde dentro del listener) y luego usarla donde la necesites, en este caso en el Adapter.