# Please provide a valid imageUri Android Studio Java

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas, resulta que estoy implementando en mi proyecto Android una imagen donde tiene texto en un recyclerview de 2 columnas, es decir, desde la camara o la galeria agrego una imagen y se añade al recyclerview, de esa forma, al pulsar sobre esa imagen me abre a otra activity donde puedo visualizar mejor la imagen. El problema esta en que cuando de esa imagen quiero realizar una extracción de texto (OCR) me salta un error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nick.escanertraductor, PID: 12841
java.lang.NullPointerException: Please provide a valid imageUri
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
    at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage.fromFilePath(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@17.2.1:2)
    at com.nick.escanertraductor.activities.ImageViewActivity.reconocerTextoImagen(ImageViewActivity.java:93)
    at com.nick.escanertraductor.activities.ImageViewActivity.access$000(ImageViewActivity.java:31)
    at com.nick.escanertraductor.activities.ImageViewActivity$1.onClick(ImageViewActivity.java:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Lo que ocurre es que detecta la imagen como que no es una uri valida y no se por que. Les dejo el codigo de mi ImageViewActivity que es donde tengo el problema.

```
private ImageView imageIv;

private Button ReconocerTexto;

private EditText TextoReconocidoET;

private Uri uri = null;

ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Reconocedor de texto
private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
private String image;

private static final String TAG = "IMAGE_TAG";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ImageView");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    imageIv = findViewById(R.id.imageIv);

    image = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Image:"+image);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(image)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_image)
            .into(imageIv);

    ReconocerTexto = findViewById(R.id.ReconocerTexto);
    TextoReconocidoET = findViewById(R.id.TextoReconocidoET);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Espere por favor");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // Esto evita que el progress dialog se cierre cuando el usuario presione fuera del progressdialog

    textRecognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    // Evento al boton
    ReconocerTexto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            reconocerTextoImagen();
        }
    });
}

private void reconocerTextoImagen() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Preparando imagen");
    progressDialog.show();

    try {
        InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(this, uri);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Reconociendo texto");
        Task<Text> textTask = textRecognizer.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Text text) {
                        // En caso de que la acción se ejecute correctamente entra en este método
                        progressDialog.dismiss(); // Descartamos el progressdialog
                        // Obtenemos el texto de la imagen
                        String texto = text.getText();
                        TextoReconocidoET.setText(texto);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // En caso contrario entraría en este otro
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(ImageViewActivity.this, "No se pudo reconocer el texto. Error "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error al preparar la imagen "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Mas tarde hice una comprobacion de si existe una imagen en el ImageViewActivity dentro del evento al botón ReconocerTexto.setOnclickListener y me salta el Toast mostrandome que debo agregar una imagen.

```
// Evento al boton
    ReconocerTexto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Comprobamos que exista una imagen seteada dentro del ListView
            if(uri == null){
                Toast.makeText(ImageViewActivity.this, "Por favor, seleccione una imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                reconocerTextoImagen();
            }
        }
    });
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que la imagen que visualice, a la hora de pulsar en el boton para reconocer el texto, verifique que esa imagen exista por asi decirlo, o sea un uri valido?

Comment: Tú estás declarando esto inicializado a `null` y ese valor no cambia en ningún momento: `private Uri uri = null;`, por eso siempre entra en esta verificación: `if(uri == null){`
. ¿Dónde se supone que se debe asignar un valor para `uri`?

Comment: se supone que es para enviar la imagen del recyclerview al activity y que ahi pueda verificar que la imagen uri existe

Comment: Es que el planteamiento del problema no es del todo claro. Lo lógico es que cada imagen del RecyclerView posea su `uri` y que al hacer click sobre cualquier imagen, obtengas dicho `uri`. ¿Es así en tu caso o no? Tú puedes pasar al Adapter del RecyclerView un `ArrayList` de objetos, que comprendan por ejemplo el título de la imagen, la `uri`, la imagen en sí misma, etc y cuando hagas click sobre cualquiera de ellas tendrás todos esos datos a mano.

Comment: [He aquí un ejemplo completo, paso por paso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967). El RecyclerView se llena de instancias de objetos de la clase `Usario`, y cuando se hace click sobre cualquier item del RecyclerView puedes obtener cualquier cosa de ese usuario. En tu caso sería lo mismo, pero con una imagen.

Comment: exacto, lo que quiero es obtener el uri de dicha imagen almacenada en el recyclerview cuando hago click, entonces, dicha imagen aparece detalladamente, o sea mas grande, en el ImageViewActivity. Dentro de ese ImageViewActivity, hay un editText bajo la imagen y un boton que cuando lo pulso reconoce el texto de la imagen. Pues al pulsar en dicho boton, es cuando me salta el error de que no es una uri valida

Comment: Pues como te dije, llena el RecyclerView con instancias de un objeto que comprenda la uri de cada imagen, y agrega un listener a los elementos del RecyclerView, de modo que cuando se haga clic sobre ellos, tengas a mano todos los datos de ese elemento. En la respuesta del enlace anterior he explicado paso a paso cómo puedes lograrlo. Entiendo que sea largo y quizá complicado si estás empezando, pero cuando aprendas a trabajar de este modo aprovecharás todas las ventajas que ofrece RecyclerView, de otro modo, escribirás un código spaghetti que, con suerte, funcionará malamente.

Comment: De acuerdo voy a intentarlo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: De nada. Y recuerda que cualquier dificultad o bloqueo mientras lo intentas puedes preguntar aquí presentando el problema concreto, y el código que tienes escrito en ese momento.

Comment: He estado mirando y analizando el codigo pero tengo una duda con respecto a cuando usar "implements RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ItemListener", ese ".ItemListener" de donde se saca, es una interfaz aparte creada o viene con el RecyclerView, es que tengo duda en eso.

Comment: Es una interfaz que se crea ahí mismo, si revisas el código en el **Paso 4:** `public interface ItemListener { void onItemClick(Usuario item); }` Eso te permitirá escuchar los clicks de cada elemento del RecyclerView en la Activity (ver **Paso 5**) sobre-escribiendo el método: `@Override public void onItemClick(Usuario item) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getId() + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }` pudiendo obtener **cualquier propiedad** de esa instancia `Usuario`.

Comment: Observa que en la Activity (**Paso 5**) tenemos `implements RecyclerViewAdapterUsuario.ItemListener`. En resumen, esto te permitirá saber, en la Activity, sobre qué item del RecyclerView se hizo clic y usar cualquier propiedad de ese item, en el caso de `Usuario`, su nombre, su apellido, su id. Trasladando eso a tu caso, pondrías el título de la imagen, la uri, etc, etc. No importa cuántas propiedades sean, porque estás recibiendo una instancia del objeto con toda la información que proporcionaste cuando lo pusiste en el RecyclerView.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya esta editado el codigo anterior

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El problema :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Please provide a valid imageUri

es causado por el valor de URI que tratas de usar en el método `.load()` de Glide, no tiene valor, su valor es null.

```
 image = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Image:"+image);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(image)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_image)
            .into(imageIv);
```

Estás recibiendo la URI en la Activity ImageViewActivity  a traves de un `Intent`, pero esta no tiene valor, debes asegurar que envías este valor correctamente, revisa:

[¿Cómo enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-datos-entre-activities?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

En el ListFragment que es donde tengo el recyclerview de la imagen tengo puesto en el metodo lo siguiente

```
private void loadImages() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: ");

    imagenesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

//        adapterImagen = new AdapterImagen(mContext, imagenesArrayList);

```
    adapterImagen = new AdapterImagen(mContext, imagenesArrayList, new RvListenerImage() {
        @Override
        public void onImageClick(ModelImage modelImage, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageUri", ""+modelImage.getImageUri());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // set adapter
    imagenList.setAdapter(adapterImagen);

    File folder = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), Constantes.IMAGES_FOLDER);

    if(folder.exists()){
        // Si la carpeta existe, intenta cargar los archivos
        Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: Si la carpeta existe, intenta cargar los archivos");
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        if(files != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: La carpeta existe y tiene imágenes");

            for(File file : files){
                Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: "+file.getName());

                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                ModelImage modelImage = new ModelImage(imageUri, false);

                imagenesArrayList.add(modelImage);
                adapterImagen.notifyItemInserted(imagenesArrayList.size());
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: La carpeta existe pero esta vacía");
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: La carpeta no existe");
    }
}
```

esto es lo que se supone que envio a la otra activity